# Use KVM to run Asterisk on AWS?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, amazon-ec2, aws, asterisk

How up to date and [useful](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27190968/262852) is AsteriskNOW?  I ask because I'm having [challenges](https://askubuntu.com/q/976143/45156) installing Asterisk on Ubuntu with `apt`.

On my local system I'm installing AsteriskNOW through `KVM` but am considering what to use with AWS.  I'm just using the "free tier" .

What would be reasonable to install to `KVM` for basic Asterisk usage -- just myself.  AsteriskNOW has the merit of being "official", not sure how FOSS it is, however.

What's a recomended way to run Asterisk on EC2?

Answer (score 1):

1) Install Centos 7

2) install freepbx using script from freepbx.org

All other projects seams become unrealible. Last realible was PIAF/incredible pbx, now they sell it to 3cx and now all project just removed.

You also can use elastix, but it not updated often anymore.

Digium not invest in AsteriskNOW at current moment, it is failed project. Started as ajax-driven unique web, now it is just enother freepbx distro. Digium investing in Switchvox(payed) now.

About KVM. Amazon EC2 is xen-driven environment. Run kvm under xen not posible in para-virt mode, only via quemu with VERY large perfomance drop. Just use centos7 ami.